# programmatically export/print to pdf

Tags: office365, office-js, word-addins

Is it possible to export/print to pdf programmatically in the Word web-app?

My research indicates that this is not currently possible but I want to be sure I do not miss anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can try this [getFileAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=word-js-preview#getfileasync-filetype--options--callback-) API:

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code for getting the document in PDF format.

```
// The following example gets the document in PDF format.
Office.context.document.getFileAsync(Office.FileType.Pdf,
    function(result) {
        if (result.status == "succeeded") {
            var myFile = result.value;
            var sliceCount = myFile.sliceCount;
            app.showNotification("File size:" + myFile.size + " #Slices: " + sliceCount);
            // Now, you can call getSliceAsync to download the files,
            // as described in the previous code segment (compressed format).

            myFile.closeAsync();
        }
        else {
            app.showNotification("Error:", result.error.message);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the sample code. This was very helpful to understand the link in the other answer. But the link in the other post was also essential. Unfortunately I could not mark 2 posts as the answer.